# Problems after reinstalling android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart

Since android studio became unable to start due to unknown cause,

https://www.resume-next.com/android-studio-no-longer-starts-after-updating/

Reinstalled referring to the above page, and selected "Uninstall the previous version".

After that, I was able to start a new version of android studio,

https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/testing/unit/mocking

If you run the test as described on the above page,

```
../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/material.dart:1:1: Error: The specified language version is too high. The highest supported language version is 2.8.
// Copyright 2014 The Flutter Authors. All rights reserved.
^
../flutter/packages/flutter_test/lib/src/_goldens_io.dart:5:1: Error: The specified language version is too high. The highest supported language version is 2.8.
// @dart = 2.10
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../flutter/packages/flutter_test/lib/src/_goldens_io.dart:65:48: Error: This requires the 'non-nullable' experiment to be enabled.
Try enabling this experiment by adding it to the command line when compiling and running.
  LocalFileComparator(Uri testFile, {path.Style? pathStyle})
                                               ^
../flutter/packages/flutter_test/lib/src/_goldens_io.dart:69:42: Error: This requires the 'non-nullable' experiment to be enabled.
Try enabling this experiment by adding it to the command line when compiling and running.
  static path.Context _getPath(path.Style? style) {
                                         ^
../flutter/packages/flutter_test/lib/src/_goldens_io.dart:73:50: Error: This requires the 'non-nullable' experiment to be enabled.
Try enabling this experiment by adding it to the command line when compiling and running.
  static Uri _getBasedir(Uri testFile, path.Style? pathStyle) {
```

I get the above error.

The result of flutter doctor is below.

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.2, on Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H2, locale ja-JP)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.1)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.0.1)
[!] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[!] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Does this require Flutter and Dart to be installed?

However, at this point, other code (default counter app, etc.) can be executed normally, so I think Flutter and Dart are already installed.

However, I think that the result of Flutter doctor says "Install Flutter and Dart".

Mac restart,
Run Flutter clean
Run Flutter upgrade
I tried above, but it doesn't change.

What should I do.
[image]